# Do votes on comments on election candidates count towards the Pundit badge?

Tags: support, election, comment-voting, comment-badges

In elections users can comment on candidates, see e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/election/2. Do votes on such comments count towards [the Pundit badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/40/pundit)? Is there a particular reason for letting them count or not count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Comment: Good answer. Is there some argument for letting those vote count rather than not letting them count?

Comment: @N.N. They're votes on comments. Why shouldn't they count?

Comment: @TheGuyWhoDisagreesWithYou I am just curious. They are indeed comments but good comments on elections candidates are to me less such that a pundit would've written them than those on normal posts. Good comments on normal posts are often stating interesting aspects pertaining to a question or an answer showing insight while good comments on election candidates are more of the critic or supporting kind which connects connects less with the stereotype of being a pundit.

Comment: Wikipedia needs a pundit to fix their sources. Are you busy this afternoon?